# YouTube data api - find purchased content

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

On the YouTube web site, there is a way of listing all the content the user has purchased. Is there an equivalent in the YouTube data api, preferably v3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest resource to a user is a Channel (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels) and according to the reference guide, it is currently not possible.